# Firebase no default constructor deserialize

Tags: java, android, firebase, jackson, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using firebase along with GeoFire, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to deserialize the GeoLocation classes.

My structure is the following:
- Root -> User -> Addresses -> Addresses Keys -> GeoLocation

The problem is that GeoLocation does not have a default constructor, only one receiving lat/long coords.

GeoLocation:

```
public final class GeoLocation {

    /** The latitude of this location in the range of [-90, 90] */
    public final double latitude;

    /** The longitude of this location in the range of [-180, 180] */
    public final double longitude;

    /**
     * Creates a new GeoLocation with the given latitude and longitude.
     *
     * @throws java.lang.IllegalArgumentException If the coordinates are not valid geo coordinates
     * @param latitude The latitude in the range of [-90, 90]
     * @param longitude The longitude in the range of [-180, 180]
     */
    public GeoLocation(double latitude, double longitude) {
        if (!GeoLocation.coordinatesValid(latitude, longitude)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Not a valid geo location: " + latitude + ", " + longitude);
        }
        this.latitude = latitude;
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }
```

Address:

```
public class Address {
    @ParcelPropertyConverter(GeoLocationParcelConverter.class)
    GeoLocation geoLocation;
}
```

And the root class to deserialize:

```
public class User {
    String uid;
    String name;
    String email;
    String profilePic;
    String profileBgPic;
    String about;
    boolean verified;
    float rating;
    Date birthday;
    String gender;
    List<Tag> specialities;
    HashMap<String, Address> addresses;
```

[image]

I've checked [Best way to retrieve/format data using Firebase Java API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17931269/best-way-to-retrieve-format-data-using-firebase-java-api) and [Jackson 3rd Party Class With No Default Constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11838039/jackson-3rd-party-class-with-no-default-constructor).
But I'm not sure how to make Firebase play along with Jackson to create a deserializer.

The error:

> Class com.firebase.geofire.GeoLocation is missing a constructor with
>   no arguments

Thanks

Comment: It will be hard to help unless you provide the [minimal, complete code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Added the classes !

Comment: If you want to read/write geo-locations to POJOs, you will need to create your own class for them. This could be a trivial subclass of `com.firebase.geofire.GeoLocation` that simply adds a default/no-argument constructor.

Comment: GeoLocation is final.